# How can I use the R arules package to operationally make recommendations?

Tags: r, data-mining, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I've successfully generated association rules using the R arules library.

What I'd like to do now is the equivalent of a prediction join in DMX. I want to take an item, and get the top 5 relevant items back.

I see the predict method in the arules library, but the documentation doesn't indicate that it is used for this type of prediction.

Taking it a step further, how do I reuse the rules I've created in a script of some sort? Should I export them to a file and import them directly every time I want to generate related items?

I'm coming from the Microsoft Data Mining world, where a model persists on a server. I'm not even sure if what I'm asking is the appropriate way to do it using R. Thanks for any guidance.